# APNS critical alert is treated as normal notification

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send critical alerts from PHP backend to my iOS app via FCM. The problem is, that the notifications are not treated as critical alerts and won´t bypass "Do Not Disturb"-mode.

**Payload sent from Backend to FCM (Example)**

```
{
    "to": "<fcm token>",
    "data": {"property-1": "value-1"},
    "priority": "high",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Hello World!",
        "body": "Lorem Ipsum ...",
        "badge": 1
        "sound": {
            "critical": 1,
            "name": "default",
            "volume": 1.0
        },
        "color": "#ffffff"
    },"time_to_live": 300,
    "content_available": true
}
```

According to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification#2990112) this format should be valid.

In settings critical alerts are enabled.

The only suspicious thing I´ve found so far, is that the `userInfo` variable holding the information of the push notification holds `sound` as JSON-string instead of a serialized object.

```
Printing description of userInfo:
▿ 4 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("gcm.message_id")
      - value : "gcm.message_id"
    - value : <message-id>
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("google.c.a.e")
      - value : "google.c.a.e"
    - value : 1
  ▿ 2 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("aps")
      - value : "aps"
    ▿ value : 4 elements
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : content-available
        - value : 1
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - key : alert
        ▿ value : 2 elements
          ▿ 0 : 2 elements
            - key : title
            - value : Hello World!
          ▿ 1 : 2 elements
            - key : body
            - value : Lorem Ipsum ...
      ▿ 2 : 2 elements
        - key : badge
        - value : 1
      ▿ 3 : 2 elements
        - key : sound
        - value : {"volume":1.0,"critical":1,"name":"default"}
  ▿ 3 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("message")
      - value : "message"
    - value : {"data":...}
```

Is this a bug in iOS or APNS?

**`{"volume":1.0,"critical":1,"name":"default"}`**

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: Does your app have a critical alert entitlement? https://medium.com/@shashidharyamsani/implementing-ios-critical-alerts-7d82b4bb5026  You can't just decide to send critical alerts. Apple has to agree that your app is worthy of bypassing a user setting and then the use has to approve it as well.

Comment: Yes, I got the entitlement and the right provisioning profile.

Comment: I don't really have an answer for you, but I know from a colleague that was straggling with silent push not working that he was able to solve this by `changing the order of the headers` of the notification. He was using AWS SNS.

Comment: ummm. I'm confused. isn't `{"volume":1.0,"critical":1,"name":"default"}` a dictionary?!

Comment: I know you've enabled critical alerts, but try doing a restart after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Critical alerts

Firstly, some information relating to Apple Push Notification Service.

From Apple docs: [criticalAlertSetting](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsettings/2963116-criticalalertsetting):

> When UNNotificationSetting.enabled, this property authorizes the app
> to play critical sounds that ignore Do Not Disturb and the device’s
> mute switch.
>
> For remote notifications, the system attempts to play a critical sound when the
> notification’s payload contains a sound directory that contains the
> critical key. Critical alerts require a special entitlement issued by
> Apple.

From Apple docs: [UNNotificationContent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationcontent):

> Don't create instances of this class directly. For remote
> notifications, the contents of this object are derived from the JSON
> payload that your server sends to the APNS server.

`UNNotificationContent` has several properties:

```
var title: String // A short description of the reason for the alert.
var subtitle: String // A secondary description of the reason for the alert.
var body: String // The message displayed in the notification alert.
var badge: NSNumber? // The number to display as the app’s icon badge.
var sound: UNNotificationSound? // The sound to play when the notification is delivered.
var launchImageName: String // The name of the launch image to display when your app is launched in response to the notification
var userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any] // A dictionary of custom information associated with the notification.
var attachments: [UNNotificationAttachment] // An array of attachments to display with the notification.
```

Notice that the `sound` property and the `userInfo` property are separate. This means that the critical alert setting must be stored under `sound` and not under `userInfo`.

---

**Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)**

Previously, Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) did not support critical alerts and it had to be done directly with Apple Push Notification Service (APNS). However, I understand the FCM API now has a `sound` property for this.

---

**Two important points**:

**1**: You must have a [critical alerts entitlement](https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/notifications-critical-alerts-entitlement/) from Apple for this to work. You have to justify why your app should be allowed to circumvent user preferences to provide a notification even when Do Not Disturb is switched on. You must then update your provisioning profile with this in Xcode.

**2**: You must also request permission specifically for critical alerts when requesting permission for notifications:

```
var authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions?
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
    authOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound, **.criticalAlert**]
} else {
    authOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
}
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:   
  authOptions!) { (granted, error) in
    // Handle outcome here
}
```

The user will then be prompted to allow critical notifications specifically.

---

In summary, this should be possible with the newer version of FCM, but will definitely work using native APNS, provided the steps above are implemented.

You might also want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53196516/8289095) for a way to use a notification extension to make the alert critical when it is received. The `mutable-content` key must be set to true, so that the notification extension is invoked.

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback! I´ll try the new FCM HTTP v1 API if it works. I also got the entitlement from Apple and the development provisioning profile with critical alerts enabled.

Comment: I tried the new FCM HTTP v1 API in combination with kreait/firebase-php and it is working like charm now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> The only suspicious thing I´ve found so far, is that the userInfo variable holding the information of the push notification holds sound as JSON-string instead of a serialized object.

That sounds indeed like the problem you could be facing. According to the Apple Documentation, the `sound` property has to be a dictionary for critical alerts ([Apple Developer – Generating a Remote Notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification#2943363)):

> A dictionary that contains sound information for critical alerts. For regular notifications, use the sound string instead.

I recommend you test sending out a push notification for testing purposes with a tool like this one [GitHub – onmyway133/PushNotifications](https://github.com/onmyway133/PushNotifications) where you specify the sound property to be a dictionary and see what happens.

Maybe this is a bug in FCM? If the test shows, that the push notification works as intended, this could be the case.

Comment: This testing tool unfortunately didn´t work, but I tried an online FCM testing tool and received the notification on iOS, but it was no critical alert.